# EDIT: Apex Batchable job not "starting"

Tags: apex, batch

We are trying to create an Apex batch job, but the start() method never seems to be called. The class we are using for the job has the following code:

```
global class BatchableScorer implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    global List<Contact> passedContacts;

    global BatchableScorer(List<Contact> passedContacts) {
        System.debug('Constructor called');
        System.debug(passedContacts);
        this.passedContacts = passedContacts;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('start() called');
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, FirstName FROM Contact]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
        System.debug('execute() called');
        for (sObject c : scope) {
            System.debug(c);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug('finish() called');
            AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors,
                JobItemsProcessed,
                TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                FROM AsyncApexJob
                WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    }
}
```

The code we are using to start up the job is:

```
BatchableScorer bct = new BatchableScorer(passedContacts);

ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(bct);
List<AsyncApexJob> myrunningjob = [Select Id, Status, ApexClass.Name From AsyncApexJob where Id=:batchprocessid];
System.debug(myrunningjob);
```

When we add the job via executeBatch, we see the constructor gets called and the debug output shows that we create a job, with an ID, with a state of 'Holding'.

When we check the Apex Jobs page there is nothing in the list, and the start() method never gets called (we don't see any debug message).

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here? Are we missing something?

EDIT: In response to questions / comments by Ajay, I just want to be clear: right now, the code executes correctly in the context of 'Execute Anonymous'. However it does not run from the VFP controller, even though it's the same code and we do see the constructor called correctly (start is not being called when in the context of the controller).

Comment: If the status is holding, then you can check the apex flex queue. There is a very good possibility that you fill find the job over there. Please check if this helps. I'll more info to this

Comment: looked into the flex queue, not showing up there either, weird it gets the batch process id but nothing else seems to happen

Comment: any chance your `List<Contact> passedContacts` is empty?

Comment: unless you are writing a managed package, the batchable class and all of the methods can be declared public, `passedContacts` should be private

Answer (score 0):

Please try once this code.

```
global class BatchableScorer implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('start() called');
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
        System.debug('execute() called');
        for (sObject c : scope) {
            System.debug(c);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug('finish() called');
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors,
                            JobItemsProcessed,
                            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                            FROM AsyncApexJob
                            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    }
}
```

**Execute anonymous**

```
BatchableScorer bs = new BatchableScorer();
Database.executeBatch(bs);
```

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: Interesting. When we run the code from Execute anonymous, everything works as expected. We can pass in a list of Contacts to the constructor and we see the start / execute / finish methods called. However, it still does not work from the VFP (we only see the constructor called).

Answer (score -1):

I am using your code and it’s executed batch. Please use this piece of code in execute anonymous. Maybe you were not passed List of Contact in Constructor.

`List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
conList.add(new Contact(LastName='Test'));
insert con;
BatchableScorer bs = new BatchableScorer(conList);
Database.executeBatch(bs);`


[image]

I hope it will help you.
Regards,
Ajay

Comment: They are not even using the `passedContacts` in the batch. The start method has its own query

Comment: Hi Eric,
Actually you are using 'passedContacts' in batch class constructor as a parameter which is list<Contact> type. so i'm creating first List<Contact> and passing list<contact> variable in the batch class contructor.

If you want to use start method query then there is no need to pass parameter in the batch class constructor.

Comment: what I mean is in the op's code they never use passedContacts so nothing to do with it could be the cause. Their start uses a simple query